# Prolog Chess AI, Alpha Beta Pruning

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning

I am relatively new to Prolog. Currently I am trying to do an AI for a Minichess Game, named Diana chess or Ladies chess (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minichess). It's basically chess but with a 6x6 Board where you don't have a queen and only one knight.

For my AI, I am mainly looking at the book *Prolog programming for artificial intelligence* by Ivan Bratko (3rd Edition). There he shows an implementation of the alpha-beta algorithm.I am also looking at the Prolog-Code someone posted on GitHub, where he implemented the same code for his Checkers game. (https://github.com/migafgarcia/prolog-checkers/blob/master/checkers.pl)

The code should think a certain number of turns ahead and choose the best move out of them. Before I started programming in Prolog I did a lot oh Java programming, that's why "Zug" in the first line of my Code is the return of NextMove. I hope this all makes some sense.

My Problem is that when I run my code and, for example, I let the AI run against a human (me), when I start as white and do my first move (b2b3), the AI just doesn't work, the backtracking kinda stops right before NextMove and that way I can't get the best move back. Furthermore when the AI thinks for the minimizing player and needs to choose his move, he always takes the move with the highest value, but, when my understanding from the algorithm is not wrong, shouldn't it take the lowest Value?

I am grateful for every comment on this or for any feedback at all.

Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/sc4gLdQe

```
alphabeta(Player,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,Board,NextMove,Eval,Depth) :-
  Depth<2,
  NewDepth is Depth+1,
  findall(
     (Player,Figur,VonL,VonR,NachL,NachR,Gegner,Board),
      zugbewegung(Player,Figur,VonL,VonR,NachL,NachR,Gegner,Board),
      Moves
  ),
  write('All Moves:'),
  sysoutMoves(Moves),nl,
  bounded_best(Player,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,Board,Moves,NextMove,Eval,NewDepth),
  write('NextMove: '),
  write(NextMove),nl,
  !.

alphabeta(Player,_,_,_,Board,_,Eval,_) :-
  value(Board,Eval,Player),
  !.

bounded_best(Player,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,Board,
            [(Spieler,Figur,VonL,VonR,NachL,NachR,Gegner,_)|Moves],
            BestMove,BestEval,Depth) :-
  sysoutMove((Spieler,Figur,VonL,VonR,NachL,NachR,Gegner,_)),
  sysoutMoves(Moves),
  ziehen(Board,(Spieler,Figur,VonL,VonR,NachL,NachR,Gegner,_),NewBoard),
  gegner(Player,NextPlayer),
  alphabeta(NextPlayer,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,NewBoard,_,Eval,Depth),
  good_enough(Player,MaxiPlayer,Moves,Alpha,Beta,Board,
             (Spieler,Figur,VonL,VonR,NachL,NachR,Gegner,_),
             Eval,BestMove,BestEval,Depth).

good_enough(_,_,[],_,_,_,_,_,_,_) :- !.

good_enough(Player,MaxiPlayer,_,_,Beta,_,Move,Eval,Move,Eval,_) :-
  minimizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval > Beta,
  !.

good_enough(Player,MaxiPlayer,_,Alpha,_,_,Move,Eval,Move,Eval,_) :-
  maximizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval < Alpha,
  !.

good_enough(Player,MaxiPlayer,Moves,Alpha,Beta,Board,Move,Eval,BestMove,BestEval,Depth) :-
  new_bounds(Player,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,Eval,NewAlpha,NewBeta),
  bounded_best(Player,MaxiPlayer,NewAlpha,NewBeta,Board,Moves,Move1,Eval1,Depth),
  better_of(Player,MaxiPlayer,Move,Eval,Move1,Eval1,BestMove,BestEval).

new_bounds(Player,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,Eval,Eval,Beta) :-
  minimizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval > Alpha,
  !.

new_bounds(Player,MaxiPlayer,Alpha,Beta,Eval,Alpha,Eval) :-
  maximizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval < Beta,
  !.

new_bounds(_,_,Alpha,Beta,_,Alpha,Beta).

better_of(Player,MaxiPlayer,Move1,Eval1,_,Eval2,Move1,Eval1) :-
  maximizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval1 >= Eval2,
  !.

better_of(Player,MaxiPlayer,_,Eval1,Move2,Eval2,Move2,Eval2) :-
  maximizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval2 >= Eval1,
  !.

better_of(Player,MaxiPlayer,Move1,Eval1,_,Eval2,Move1,Eval1) :-
  minimizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval1 =< Eval2,
  !.

better_of(Player,MaxiPlayer,_,Eval1,Move2,Eval2,Move2,Eval2) :-
  minimizing(Player,MaxiPlayer),
  Eval2 =< Eval1,
  !.

maximizing(Player,MaxiPlayer) :-
  Player == MaxiPlayer.

minimizing(Player,MaxiPlayer) :-
  Player \== MaxiPlayer.
```

Comment: When you say "the backtracking kinda stops right before NextMove", do you mean that you see the "All Moves:" output, but then you don't see the "NextMove:" output? That means that `bounded_best` fails. Which means that either (a) the call doesn't match any clause head for `bounded_best`, or (b) something fails *inside* a clause for `bounded_best`. You could try to learn how to use a Prolog debugger (if your Prolog system has one), or add lots of print statements inside `bounded_best`, `good_enough`, and wherever else execution takes you.

Comment: That's the part I dont really understand. ´´´´   bounded_best   ´´´´ fails, but when I fill it with a lot of print statements it doesn't even write the first print, which should be called before anything else. This would mean, that the call doesn't match any clause head, but when I print all the variables I use for ````   bounded_best   ```` I get all the things I need.

Comment: Is the list of moves non-empty, like `bounded_best` expects? You could replace the list in the clause head with a variable `AllMoves` and print its value before doing `AllMoves = [(Spieler, Figur, ...) | Moves]`.